# Magento : Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1, login

I can' t log in anymore. It show

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in /usr/www/users/x/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php on line 55**

This is on line 55:
**$user = $session->getUser();**

Can anyone help me?

Best,
Mark

Comment: did you get the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Magento 1.9.3.3, and some of its core files has deprecated and Magento community released the new version and solved all issue that occurred in previous version. I was having the same issue. What I have did I have replace the core files with the updated version. And Site working fine.